# Outlook 2007 + Exchange 2010 (Save All Attachments)

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, attachments, exchange-2010

About 3 weeks back our company upgraded our mail system to Exchange 2010, all went smooth, few issues but nothing major.

A few days ago we had a call from a colleague where he was unable to save all attachments, From `File > Save As > Save All Attachments`.

When the email has a single attachment it works perfectly normal, and depending on the file type it allows you to save multiple attachments.

But there's a lot of file types that will not work, such as zip, pdf, doc etc, Usually we get a location box open up asking where we would like to drop the attachments, but it does nothing, You click `Save All Attachments` and nothing happens.

After hours of research I have come across mixed results, a lot of people on forums have been explaining that they have recently crossed over to Exchange 2010 and there issues started there.

But on the other hand Microsoft released a KB ([278188](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278188)) which was depressing if that, but that article was published in 2007, as stated by the time stamp, and Exchange 2010 has only come out recently.

Im looking to see if you guys have any clues what could be causing this, anything server side that I can take a look at (AD, Exchange, ...).

Any help on this is greatly supported

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you know the work around by now.  CTRL - Click the documents you want to save and right click on one of them and choose Save As...  This of course isn't a fix by any means, but it is the best workaround that I have seen since this problem started.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI:

This has been fixed with the SP1 for Exchange 2010.
It was also an issue on Outlook 2003 clients.
But I recommend to install directly the latest Update Roll-Up since the basic SP1 package causes more problems than it solves.

Cheers
Alex

Answer (score 0):

There is a hotfix from Microsoft that describes exactly your problem:

Quote:

- Consider the following scenario:
     Your mailbox is moved to Microsoft Exchange Server 2010.
     In Office Outlook 2007, you open an email message that contains an attachment. 
     The message was sent by an external user.
     You click the Microsoft Office button, point to Save As, and then click Save Attachments.  In this scenario, the attachment is not
  saved as expected.

You must have SP1 or SP2 installed to use it. It can not be downloaded directly, you will have to contact Microsoft to get it.

Description: [MSKB 2276479](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2276479) from Microsoft.